# How to set http request time out in Liferay server

Tags: http, timeout, liferay, httprequest

I'm currently working on a Liferay project. The http request time out is limited to 30seconds in 1st attempt and 1 min in the second attempt. I'm just breaking my head how can I change the http request time because I dont want it to be 30seconds for 1st attempt and I should be able to modify it. Any help would be appreciated. TY.

*`Observations:`*

- If the first request is taking more than 30 seconds, the request is
  getting aborted and new request is being made by itself.
- If the second request is taking more than 1 minute, the page is
  getting broken.

[image]

Comment: Are you running Liferay in a load balanced environment or behind a firewall? What is your platform (default tomcat or another app server)? Please give us more information about your config.

Comment: https://web.liferay.com/community/forums/-/message_boards/message/84389895

Comment: @VC1 it is tomcat.

Answer (score 0):

Try to increase asyncTimeout in "tomcat-8.0.32\conf\server.xml" like below.

```
<Connector port="8080" protocol="HTTP/1.1"
  connectionTimeout="20000" asyncTimeout ="600000" 
  redirectPort="8443" URIEncoding="UTF-8" />
```